# Why 2 registers are required in construction of Regular Boolean MRSW Register?

Tags: multiprocessing, cpu-registers, multiprocessor

```
public class RegBoolMRSWRegister implements Register<Boolean>
    private boolean old; 
    private SafeBoolMRSWRegister value;
    public void write(boolean x ) { 
           if (old != x ) { 
               value.write(x); 
               old = x ; 
                          }
    }  

    public boolean read() { return value.read (); }
 }
```

In the above code two variables are used old and value. However according to me one can do the same with one variable only that is value.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand this, you need to understand the difference between safe and regular registers.  A safe register with a read() concurrent with a write() can return any value.  A regular register can only return the previous value or the value being written.  If we didn't have the check, then we could be writing a value of 1 to a register with a previous value of 1 in it.  Since the underlying register is safe, its read() is allowed to return any value.  It could return 0.  However, 0 is NOT acceptable for a regular register since it is neither the previous value or the value being written.  Only writing the register when it is changing limits you to either the other binary value or the new value.  (Since this is a binary register, there are only 2 possible values.).

Here is some additional information as an answer to your comment.  (My comment to yours was too long for the comment section.)

The reason that your one variable solution doesn't work is that when you do the value.get() to read the register, you can't tell if the value you are getting is the correct value or not.  Since it is a read of a safe register, you could be getting any value.  You can't tell if it is time to write the register because the read value isn't necessarily correct.

Here is the concrete example:
    Register value = 0
    You want to write = 1
    get() returns = 1

In this case, since the value you want to write equals the value the get() returns, you won't do anything.  This keeps the register with a value of 0, when you really wanted it to be 1.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yah that part is understood. But considering that part we can also do the same thing with 1 variable value. Say

    if(x!=value.get())   value.write(x);

My question is basically what is the problem in such implementation.

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general writer thread is separate thread (not one from readers), so you simply cannot read from MRSW safe boolean register by writer thread, because that register doesn't hold value for writer, it can only write to register. That's why you actually need second simple variable to hold previously written value. That's it.